# How to get rid of the following error when trying to build dynamic queries in Spring Boot using JPASpecificationExecutor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, backend

I wanted to search the table based on filters. The filters could have any combination so used JPASpecificationExecutor. I'm receiving the query as RequestBody in the SearchController in the defined format.

I build a SpecificationBuilder Class to build the Specification Object of the Entity Type.

Error:
`UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'searchController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'searchService': Error creating bean with name 'searchService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository': Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.sub.sublayer.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on SublayerApplication: Failed to convert property value of type 'jdk.proxy4.$Proxy87 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager'; Cannot convert value of type 'jdk.proxy4.$Proxy87 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found`

I build the Specification Object and passed it in the findAll() method.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends  JpaRepository<User, Long>,JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
}
```

the pom.xml, in order to check the dependencies and their versions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sub</groupId>
    <artifactId>sublayer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sublayer</name>
    <description>subs downstream</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```